# Delete dial call number from recent call list in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a some special requirement to delete dial call number from call list. I research a lot on SO but not able to get any answer for this. Is it possible in iPhone?

Comment: It is not possibly using publicly-available APIs.  It _may_ be possible when jailbreaking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple doesn't allow developers to modify call list or history, since it will violate user's privacy policy. It is not possible to achieve in iOS with iOS public framework, used to submit apps to appstore. It is only possible by using private frameworks... or you can say jailbreaking the device. But you won't be able to submit app to store. It will be rejected.

Comment: can you please provide me the relative document list for this?

Comment: You can browse apple docs and see what methods have they revealed in their Telephony or other call related frameworks. It is mentioned in their rules that if you will use any private API, your app will be rejected. You still want links?

Comment: No i will explain. Thanks for tour answer

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer: No you cannot. Apple iOS doesn't allow you to access some of the applications such as Phone and Messages - So it is not possible for you directly access the call log, read messages or whatsoever. What you can do is, you can open the Messages/Phone app with a pre-defined number to call or a message to send for performing user verification actions.

Take the example of Uber app; you can call the driver by tapping on the Contact button, but there is no way that app can access your phone log and delete the recent numbers from the record - unlike Android devices.

It may be possible by jailbreaking, which on the other hand won't let you put your app on the App Store.

Comment: Thanks for your answer